# DBpedia SPARQL Query US Universities

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I created a SPARQL query that I'm running on the [DBpedia SNORQL SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/). The purpose of the query is to get a list of universities or colleges in the United States, including their longitude, latitude, and endowment. The query seems to be working but seems to be missing some records and/or attributes. So, for example, Harvard University doesn't show up in the result, even though its [DBpedia record](http://dbpedia.org/page/Harvard_University) exists and the attributes should match my query. I'm not sure why that record doesn't show up. Another example is [University of Massachusetts Boston](http://dbpedia.org/page/University_of_Massachusetts_Boston), which comes up as a query result, but the result doesn't get the longitude and latitude attributes, even though the record contains those attributes.  Here's the SPARQL Query:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX d: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?uni ?link ?lat ?long ?endowment
WHERE {
?s foaf:homepage ?link ;
   rdf:type <http://schema.org/CollegeOrUniversity> ;
rdfs:label ?uni
OPTIONAL {?s geo:lat ?lat ;
             geo:long ?long . 
          ?s d:endowment ?endowment . }
FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?uni), 'en'))

{?s dbpedia2:country "U.S."@en . }
UNION
{?s dbpedia2:country "U.S." . }
UNION
{?s d:country :United_States . }

}
ORDER BY ?s
```

Answer (score 5):

The query you posted will only select entities with a `foaf:homepage` and [Harvard University](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard_University) does not have one.  (That is, the resource does not have a `foaf:homepage` property.  Obviously the university does have a homepage.)  [UMass Boston](http://dbpedia.org/resource/UMass_Boston) doesn't match the optional pattern --

```
OPTIONAL {?s geo:lat ?lat ;
             geo:long ?long . 
          ?s d:endowment ?endowment . }
```

-- because that pattern only matches when `?s` has a `geo:lat`, a `geo:long`, and a `d:endowment`.  Though the pattern is optional, the whole pattern must either match or not;  you do not get partial matches.

Here's your query, reworked to use [the built-in namespaces that the DBPedia SPARQL endpoint currently supports](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?help=nsdecl)  (that list is subject to change over time), with the `OPTIONAL` parts broken down as necessary, and moved to the end.  (Moving them to the end is just an aesthetic consideration.)  I tried some various constraints, and it is interesting to note that only 32 universities have the `dbpprop:country "U.S."@en`, but 273 have `dbpprop:country "United States"@en`.  There are 7620 results in total.

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?label ?homepage ?lat ?long ?endowment
WHERE {
  ?school a <http://schema.org/CollegeOrUniversity> 
  { ?school dbpedia-owl:country dbpedia:United_States }
  UNION
  { ?school dbpprop:country dbpedia:United_States }
  UNION 
  { ?school dbpprop:country "U.S."@en }
  UNION 
  { ?school dbpprop:country "United States"@en }

  OPTIONAL { ?school rdfs:label ?label .
             FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), 'en')) }
  OPTIONAL { ?school foaf:homepage ?homepage }
  OPTIONAL { ?school geo:lat ?lat ; geo:long ?long }
  OPTIONAL { ?school dbpedia-owl:endowment ?endowment }
}
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbpedia-owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpprop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Flabel%20%3Fhomepage%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%20%3Fendowment%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fschool%20a%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FCollegeOrUniversity%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fschool%20dbpedia-owl%3Acountry%20dbpedia%3AUnited_States%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fschool%20dbpprop%3Acountry%20dbpedia%3AUnited_States%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20UNION%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fschool%20dbpprop%3Acountry%20%22U.S.%22%40en%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20UNION%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fschool%20dbpprop%3Acountry%20%22United%20States%22%40en%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fschool%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fschool%20foaf%3Ahomepage%20%3Fhomepage%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fschool%20geo%3Alat%20%3Flat%20%3B%20geo%3Along%20%3Flong%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fschool%20dbpedia-owl%3Aendowment%20%3Fendowment%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)

Comment: I currently get an error `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 16: Undefined namespace prefix at 'dbpedia-owl' before 'dbpedia:United_States'` when running this query at the stated endpoint. There is no `dbpedia-owl` PREFIX listed currently. I'll try changing it to `owl` and/or removing that union element, and compare the result count.

Comment: After removing the `dbpedia-owl` line I get ` Undefined namespace prefix at 'dbpprop' before 'dbpedia:United_States' `. Any chance you can update this for the current query system? I'll keep searching for clues...

Comment: @user3175580 DBpedia's SPARQL endpoint changed a bunch of the predefined namespace prefixes without preserving the old ones. The list of current ones is here: http://dbpedia.org/sparql?help=nsdecl . I just updated this one, but I have about [200 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1281433+%5Bsparql%5D+%5Bdbpedia%5D+is%3Aanswer) regarding DBpedia and SPARQL, so I don't really have the time to fix most of them, unfortunately.

Comment: OK, thanks! It seems, however, that DBpedia is currently missing a lot of universities with this search. I even changed `?school a` to `dbpedia-owl:EducationalInstitution`, but results are missing almost all of University of California, including http://dbpedia.org/page/University_of_California_Los_Angeles -- seems like this entry has no attributes indicating it's a school.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `foaf:homepage` but some of them do not have this assigned. That is the first thing that caught my eyes. Check the rest of the query by removing bit by bit each element and see what the result set has to offer.