# SPARQL get dbpedia ressources by category

Tags: sparql, geosparql

I'm a beginner in SPARQL. And I'm having problems to get the latitude and longitude of all university by city on DBpedia.

I tried multiple things without success.
[This](http://dbpedia.org/page/Paris) page shows the universities of Paris on the `dbo:campus` property, so I like to get the list of the universities with this property and after that get the geographics coordinates.

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?name, ?univ, ?lat, ?long WHERE {
    ?p rdf:type dbo:Place.
    ?p rdfs:label ?name.
    ?p dbo:campus ?u.
    ?u geo:lat ?lat.
    ?u geo:long ?long.
    ?u rdfs:label ?univ
    FILTER(LANG(?name) = "en").
    FILTER(?name = "Paris")
}
```

I check this post [DBpedia SPARQL Query US Universities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056476/dbpedia-sparql-query-us-universities) but it doesn't work with another country.

Comment: Thanks so much @TallTed for your comment, that really helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you read "is `SOME_PROPERTY` of"on a rendered DBpedia page, this means the inverse direction, i.e., it shows the triple in its inverted form. Thus, you have to invert the triple pattern in the SPARQL query. For your example, it means that universities are the subject and Paris the object:

   `?u dbo:campus ?p`
2. The labels are language tagged in DBpedia; thus, `FILTER(?name = "Paris")` is not enough. Adding the English language tag helps:

   `FILTER(?name = "Paris"@en)`

A working query would be

```sql
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?name, ?univ WHERE {
    ?p rdf:type dbo:Place.
    ?p rdfs:label ?name.
    ?u dbo:campus ?p.
    ?u geo:lat ?lat.
    ?u geo:long ?long.
    ?u rdfs:label ?univ
    FILTER(LANG(?name) = "en").
    FILTER(?name = "Paris"@en)
}
```

Some comments:

- Using the label to match a resource can lead to unwanted results. Resources are identified by URIs; thus, use the URI if possible. The `VALUES` clause is a cool feature of SPARQL 1.1 to support inline data.
- **If** you use the URI, you could omit the `rdf:type` triple pattern since you wouldn't have to filter for resources of a specific type given the label.
- The official SPARQL standard doesn't allow commas in between the projection variables; this is Virtuoso-specific syntax.
- SPARQL supports the more compact Turtle syntax.
- A `FILTER` doesn't need a `.` at the end.
- Try to use `LANGMATCHES` for matching languages in literals.

A "better" query could be:

```sql
PREFIX  geo:  <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  dbr:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT  ?name ?univ ?lat ?long
WHERE
  { VALUES ?p { dbo:Paris }
    ?p  rdfs:label  ?name .
    ?u  dbo:campus  ?p ;
        geo:lat     ?lat ;
        geo:long    ?long ;
        rdfs:label  ?univ
    FILTER langMatches(lang(?name), "en")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The SPARQL query you provided retrieves the name, latitude, and longitude of universities in Paris. To get the latitude and longitude of all universities by city on DBpedia, you can modify the query as follows:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?name ?univ ?lat ?long WHERE {
    ?p rdf:type dbo:Place.
    ?p rdfs:label ?name.
    ?p dbo:campus ?u.
    ?u geo:lat ?lat.
    ?u geo:long ?long.
    ?u rdfs:label ?univ
    FILTER(LANG(?name) = "en").
    FILTER(LANG(?univ) = "en").
    FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?univ), "university")).
    FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?name), "city name"))
}
```